# Regex for finding strings greater then 20 or less then 5 after ":"

Tags: regex

I have a large dataset then I need to clean up using regular expression in Sublime text editor.

I'm trying to remove anything after that's less than 5 characters after a colon(:), including blanks.
Also trying to remove anything greater than 20 characters.

Example:

- jshfdgl:jss
- oiadfgopiafdg:
- ofdijgdf:2)
- ogijdfogis:_ge
- iognhif:gojdf sdofig peoji-009
- ogijdfs:_ge 2

these should all fall under the regex...

Im also trying to use lookbehind the colon to find characters less then 5 and greater then 20.

Been trying many things but it seems to keep missing spaces..

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: add some code to the question

Comment: Simplest is to split the text on the colon and determine the length of the two parts. Why is there any need for regex?

Comment: `Been trying many things...` Please post these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<=:)(?:.{0,5}|.{20,})$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/udDLLu/2)

Replace the match with a blank string

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=:)` - finds the position immediately preceded by a `:`
- `(?:.{0,5}|.{20,})`

  - `.{0,5}` - matches 0 to 5 occurrences of any character except a newline
  - `|` - OR
  - `.{20,}` - matches 20 or more occurrences of any character except a new line
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: That's perfect, and what would you do to select anything greater than 12 characters before a colon?

Comment: To select such strings, you can get an idea from this [`^[^:\s]{12,}(?=:)`](https://regex101.com/r/udDLLu/4)

Answer (score 0):

According to the advice by *@Andy G* (which I support),
I prepared a solution, which instead of regex, uses the following *perl*
one-liner script (to execute from the command prompt):

```
perl -lan -F: -e "$len = length($F[1]); printf(qq(%s:%s\n), $F[0], ($len > 5 && $len <= 20)?$F[1]:'')" inp.txt >out.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-lan` - *perl* options: `-l` - chop input line terminator,
  `-a` - *auto-split* mode,
  `-n` - "looping" execution.
- `-F:` - Another *perl* option - define *auto-split* separator (`:`).
  Thanks to it, input line is split, just on ":" and the result is saved
  in predefined array `F`.
- `-e "..."` - The program (*one-liner* script) to execute.
- `inp.txt` - Input file name.
- `>out.txt` - Output redirection.

And now move on to the script content:

- `$len = length($F[1]);` - Save length of the second "input segment"
  (after ":").
- `printf( ... )` - Formatted print of the output line, arguments described below.
- `qq(%s:%s\n)` - Format string. `qq` operator is used to embed additional
  double quotes around the format string, between "plain" double quotes
  surrounding the script content.
- `$F[0]` - The first string to print - first "input segment" (before ":").
- `($len > 5 && $len <= 20)?$F[1]:''` - The second string to print.
  Actually it is *ternary* operator, decicing which string to print:
  If the saved length is within allowed limits then print the second
  "input segment" (after ":"), otherwise the instruction prints an
  empty string.

Due to `-n` option, this program is repeated for each input line.

Of course, you must have *perl* installed on your computer.

If you need further explanation, read about *perl one-liners* and
maybe also about *perl* itself.